# How to use Transient in Jpa.accually i used @Transient.but it is not effected.i had written like this

Tags: jpa, transient

'@Transient
    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    } '

Answer (score 0):

Transient means that the value is not going to be serialized to DB.

You put on the class property (if the JPA access is by fields, which is the default option) or on the getter (not setter, if your jpa uses the methods instead of the fields).